# Why my for loop is returning chars intead strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to python. I am trying to achieve this result:

> "Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"

My code is generating this:

> M, i, k, eK, a, r, e, nJ, a, k, eT, a, s, h, a

Why is join method not working? Or what am I doing wrong?

```
def group_list(group, users):
    members =''
    for user in users:
        members += ', '.join(user)
    return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
```

Comment: Just `return ', '.join(users)`

Comment: The argument you pass to `', '.join` should be a sequence. If you pass a string, like `'Mike'`, then it is treated as a sequence of characters, `M,i,k,e` that you are joining with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the simplest answer, here it is:

```
def group_list(group, users):
    return ', '.join(users)
```

In your script, you join each *word* in users, not the *list* of users itself. To recreate this bug for further investigation, you can write this line:

```
print(', '.join("Mike"))

# M, i, k, e
```

The `join` method's signature is as follows:

```
string.join(iterable)
```

An iterable, is well, something you can iterate through. Strings are considered an iterable data type, similar to lists. You can think of passing a string into the `join` method as similar to passing a list in - it will treat it the same.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you haven't use group at all.
Don't know what's that for.

If you want to use join(), you don't need a for loop.

```
def group_list(group, users):
    members = ''
    members += ', '.join(users)
    return members
```

Comment: You don't need `+=` either. You could just return `', '.join(users)`

Comment: Oooo, another way to shorten code, thank you for the suggestion!